# Using SimpleCursorAdapter and ArrayAdapter in a CustomAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter, custom-adapter

I have a `ListView`, the first 5 elements of which is to be populated by elements retrieved from an array defined in the **strings.xml**. These are static and will never change. The rest of the elements will be populated from the **SQLite DB**. These are dynamic and the user can remove from and add to these.

Is there a way I can implement a **custom adapter** where I can use a combination of `ArrayAdapter` and `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

I tried searching online for such a combination, but could not find anything that could help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you try only ArrayAdapter by retrieving data from db to an array

Comment: Make a common ArrayList combining ArrayAdapter data and SimpleCursorAdapter data and use a single ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: Create a new arraylist having values from your string.xml and from the  database then pass that list into the listview adapter

Comment: Yes @john and praveen. I can do that. But then I'll have to implement my own **Loader** to manage the dynamic data, which I want to avoid if possible.

Comment: You might look into CommonsWare's [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).